# How set html5 javadoc option in Gradle build with Kotlin

Tags: gradle, build, kotlin, javadoc

In groovy format I have to set javadoc task like that to have html5 doc

```
javadoc {
    options.addBooleanOption('html5', true)
}
```

I'm trying to set html5 option in a Gradle Kotlin format build but didn't find how to do this. I guess, I must start with something like that:

```
tasks.withType<Javadoc> {
    options.?
}
```

Thxs

Comment: I reformat, hope It's more clear.

Comment: Sure. But you can drop that thxs or so. We dont usually have these salutations here. Just upvote good answers, and timely accept them.

Answer (score 5):

Here is solution:

```
tasks.withType<Javadoc> {
    (options as StandardJavadocDocletOptions).addBooleanOption("html5", true)
}
```